# error: Dereference of undefined pointer value

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, malloc, realloc

I'm trying to malloc/realloc memory for an array of trace_t structs.

```
typedef struct {
    step_t *head;     // pointer to the step in the head of the trace
    step_t *tail;     // pointer to the step in the tail of the trace
} trace_t;
```

The code runs fine (i think) but my compiler outputted a "dereference of undefined pointer value" warning. What does this mean? On the line that is causing the error I'm only trying to set the head and tail pointers of each trace_t in the trace_t array to NULL

```
trace_t** 
make_trace_array(trace_t** trace_arr, int request, int limit) {
    int i;
    if (request==MALLOC) {
        trace_arr = (trace_t**)malloc(limit*sizeof(*trace_arr));
        assert(trace_arr!=NULL);
        for (i=0; i<limit; i++) {
            trace_arr[i]->head = trace_arr[i]->tail = NULL; <------------- warning
        }
        return trace_arr;
    } else if (request==REALLOC) {
        trace_arr = (trace_t**)realloc((trace_t**)trace_arr, (limit*2)*sizeof(*trace_arr));
        assert(trace_arr!=NULL);
        // may b bug
        for (i=limit; i<limit*2; i++) {
            trace_arr[i]->head = trace_arr[i]->tail = NULL; <------------- warning
        }
        return trace_arr;
    }
    printf("Invalid request");
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: You `malloc` an array of initialized pointers then try to use those pointers.

Comment: @user3121023 Thanks! That got rid of the warning. I over complicated the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the pointer produced by this expression

```
trace_arr[i]
```

has indeterminate value.

That is you did not initialized the dynamically allocated array pointed to by the pointer `trace_arr`.

In for loops like for example this

```
 for (i=0; i<limit; i++) {
            trace_arr[i]->head = trace_arr[i]->tail = NULL; <------------- warning
        }
    }
```

you need insert a memory allocation for elements `trace_arr[i]`.

Something like

```
trace_arr[i] = malloc( sizeof( trace_t ) );
```

Pay attention to that the function is unsafe. For example the function realloc used in this statement

```
trace_arr = (trace_t**)realloc((trace_t**)trace_arr, (limit*2)*sizeof(*trace_arr));
```

can return a null-pointer. In this case after the assignment you will lost the original pointer to the previously allocated memory.

A better approach is declare the function the following way

```
int make_trace_array(trace_t ***trace_arr, int request, int limit);
```

That is the function will return either success or failure and the original poiner will be passed to the function by value. Within function you have to check whether a call of malloc or  realloc was successfull.

Comment: Ahhh I see, thanks. Should I use a for loop and run malloc() on each trace_arr[i] instead?

Comment: Welcome to the world of three-star-programmers. :)

Answer (score 2):

You want an array of structs, but you handle it like an array of pointers.
You need to get rid of one level of indirection.
This could look as follows (not compiled):

```
trace_t* 
make_trace_array(trace_t** trace_arr, int request, int limit) {
    int i;
    assert(trace_arr != NULL);
    if (request==MALLOC) {
        trace_t *arr = malloc(limit*sizeof(*arr));
        assert(arr!=NULL);
        for (i=0; i<limit; i++) {
            arr[i].head = arr[i].tail = NULL;
        }
        *trace_arr = arr;
        return arr;
    } else if (request==REALLOC) {
        trace_t *arr = realloc(*trace_arr, (limit*2)*sizeof(*arr));
        assert(arr!=NULL);
        for (i=limit; i<limit*2; i++) {
            arr[i].head = arr[i].tail = NULL;
        }
        *trace_arr = arr;
        return arr;
    }
    printf("Invalid request");
    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assigning a value to `trace_arr` does not assign any value to `trace_arr[i]` but you use `trace_arr[i]` in `trace_arr[i]->head = …`